# Codename1 side menu misplacement

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to specify sidemenu width with the follow code:

```
    Hashtable<String, Integer> h = new Hashtable<>();
    h.put("sideMenuSizePortraitInt", 50);
    h.put("sideMenuSizeLandscapeInt", 30);
    UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(h);
```

But the result has some misplacement, please see the picture. Anybody knows how to fix this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLSB5.png)

Comment: The issue happens on iOS 10.1.1. It works fine on Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea. This will break your theme entirely as it will replace all existing theming in the app. Theme constants are added in the designer tool by double clicking the res file, selecting the theme and then going to the 5th tab for the constants.

If you insist on doing this thru code I suggest using `addThemeProps` and not `setThemeProps`. Theme constants start with the `@` symbol to signify that they are constants.

Comment: I am not insisting to do that way. The only purpose is to limit side menu width (the default is almost 90% of screen width, which does not look good). Is it possible to set width auto-adapt to the menu item with max width?

Comment: You can just change the same variable by using the theme constants UI which is the "right place" to do this.

Comment: I am still confused with ui and theme builder. All my ui is hand-coded now. Can I hand-code side menu width?

Comment: The theme tool is still used even in handcoded application. Just double click the res file. Select "Theme" select the "Constants" tab press add and select the constants. Give them the right values.